# Fetch Dataframe Pandas with Cassandra Json Rows

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, cassandra

I get a JSON like this every 30s:

```
{
  mac: "IAHXUH7DMZJ4"
  name: "B14"
  desc: "B14"
  -loc: {
    lat: 49.819225
    lng: 1.980784
    levelId: 0
    prec: 3.75
  }
  lrrt: 0
  -rss: {
    F45EAB0C14C7: -76
    F45EAB0C0ED5: -76
    F45EAB142A61: -90
    F45EAB0C0EC7: -84
    F45EAB08AAAD: -91
    F45EAB0C1B67: -90
    F45EAB0C1978: -79
  }
}
-{
  mac: "IA9M9XAO7980"
  name: "B19"
  desc: "B19"
  -loc: {
    lat: 48.819617
    lng: 1.980747
    levelId: 0
    prec: 3.75
  }
  lrrt: 0
  -rss: {
    F45EAB0C14C7: -59
    F45EAB0C0ED5: -67
    F45EAB142A61: -80
    F45EAB0C0EC7: -62
    F45EAB08AAAD: -81
    F45EAB0C1B67: -86
    F45EAB0BF97E: -79
    F45EAB0C1978: -74
  }
}
-{
  mac: "I2JW3FLCFIK6"
  name: "B34"
  desc: "B34"
  -loc: {
    lat: 48.819736
    lng: 1.950706
    levelId: 0
    prec: 3.75
  }
  lrrt: 1521272
  -rss: {
    F45EAB0C14C7: -87
    F45EAB0C0ED5: -76
    F45EAB142A61: -72
    F45EAB0C0EC7: -83
    F45EAB08AAAD: -86
    F45EAB0C1B67: -69
    F45EAB0BF97E: -87
    F45EAB0C1978: -88
  }
}
```

**EDIT WITH THE FULL JSON INPUT DATA**

```
[{"mac":"IAHXUH9DMZJ4","name":"B14","desc":"B14","loc":{"lat":41.819225,"lng":1.980784,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-76,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-76,"F45EAB142A61":-90,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-84,"F45EAB08AAAD":-91,"F45EAB0C1B67":-90,"F45EAB0C1978":-79}},{"mac":"IAOM9XAO7980","name":"B19","desc":"B19","loc":{"lat":41.819217,"lng":1.980747,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-59,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-67,"F45EAB142A61":-80,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-62,"F45EAB08AAAD":-81,"F45EAB0C1B67":-86,"F45EAB0BF97E":-79,"F45EAB0C1978":-74}},{"mac":"I2JW3WLCFIK6","name":"B34","desc":"B34","loc":{"lat":41.819136,"lng":1.980706,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":1521272,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-87,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-76,"F45EAB142A61":-72,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-83,"F45EAB08AAAD":-86,"F45EAB0C1B67":-69,"F45EAB0BF97E":-87,"F45EAB0C1978":-88}},{"mac":"I2GAUGLJC0FP","name":"B2","desc":"B2","loc":{"lat":41.819077,"lng":1.980771,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":1621090,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-90,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-86,"F45EAB142A61":-86,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-79,"F45EAB08AAAD":-84,"F45EAB0C1B67":-87,"F45EAB0BF97E":-57,"F45EAB0C1978":-78}},{"mac":"IC7UO5I0SJLW","name":"B27","desc":"B27","loc":{"lat":41.819073,"lng":1.980769,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-85,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-90,"F45EAB142A61":-89,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-85,"F45EAB08AAAD":-81,"F45EAB0C1B67":-86,"F45EAB0BF97E":-59,"F45EAB0C1978":-89}},{"mac":"IEQFQSVBB5X4","name":"B6","desc":"B6","loc":{"lat":41.819089,"lng":1.980768,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-77,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-83,"F45EAB142A61":-89,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-87,"F45EAB08AAAD":-89,"F45EAB0C1B67":-84,"F45EAB0BF97E":-63,"F45EAB0C1978":-85}},{"mac":"I1PEA8FWMOSM","name":"B43","desc":"B43","loc":{"lat":41.819082,"lng":1.980765,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-87,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-90,"F45EAB142A61":-89,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-78,"F45EAB08AAAD":-79,"F45EAB0C1B67":-90,"F45EAB0BF97E":-64,"F45EAB0C1978":-87}},{"mac":"I428SMQOUF5G","name":"B5","desc":"B5","loc":{"lat":41.819074,"lng":1.980770,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-75,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-87,"F45EAB142A61":-82,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-80,"F45EAB08AAAD":-78,"F45EAB0C1B67":-81,"F45EAB0BF97E":-53,"F45EAB0C1978":-81}},{"mac":"IEM0XRC99VL7","name":"B49","desc":"B49","loc":{"lat":41.819225,"lng":1.980765,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-69,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-75,"F45EAB142A61":-89,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-74,"F45EAB08AAAD":-94,"F45EAB0C1B67":-86,"F45EAB0BF97E":-86,"F45EAB0C1978":-73}},{"mac":"I6FZ8Y1N2RKZ","name":"B46","desc":"B46","loc":{"lat":41.819095,"lng":1.980758,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-84,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-90,"F45EAB142A61":-92,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-80,"F45EAB08AAAD":-81,"F45EAB0C1B67":-87,"F45EAB0BF97E":-69,"F45EAB0C1978":-88}},{"mac":"I6Z5U4QOM1Q4","name":"B9","desc":"B9","loc":{"lat":41.819214,"lng":1.980801,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-65,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-59,"F45EAB142A61":-81,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-65,"F45EAB08AAAD":-85,"F45EAB0C1B67":-76,"F45EAB0BF97E":-71,"F45EAB0C1978":-69}},{"mac":"IF08T5HT0VYO","name":"B10","desc":"B10","loc":{"lat":41.819234,"lng":1.980723,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-45,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-77,"F45EAB142A61":-87,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-80,"F45EAB08AAAD":-93,"F45EAB0C1B67":-90,"F45EAB0BF97E":-85,"F45EAB0C1978":-84}},{"mac":"I5WI5GKMQ86J","name":"B28","desc":"B28","loc":{"lat":41.819067,"lng":1.980693,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":1045840,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-90,"F45EAB142A61":-87,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-89,"F45EAB08AAAD":-74,"F45EAB0C1B67":-86,"F45EAB0BF97E":-88}},{"mac":"I9ZVTWFMH4TZ","name":"B13","desc":"B13","loc":{"lat":41.819076,"lng":1.980770,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-78,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-88,"F45EAB142A61":-87,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-81,"F45EAB08AAAD":-90,"F45EAB0C1B67":-86,"F45EAB0BF97E":-57,"F45EAB0C1978":-83}},{"mac":"I5SSGFIESFQU","name":"B7","desc":"B7","loc":{"lat":41.819089,"lng":1.980760,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-76,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-82,"F45EAB142A61":-87,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-85,"F45EAB08AAAD":-76,"F45EAB0C1B67":-81,"F45EAB0BF97E":-63,"F45EAB0C1978":-84}},{"mac":"I5OKP2GB02UG","name":"B8","desc":"B8","loc":{"lat":41.819206,"lng":1.980755,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":34274,"rss":{"F45EAB0C0EC7":-73,"F45EAB0C1978":-82}},{"mac":"I66Q712PTY7O","name":"B29","desc":"B29","loc":{"lat":41.819084,"lng":1.980765,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":1521330,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-83,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-89,"F45EAB142A61":-85,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-79,"F45EAB08AAAD":-86,"F45EAB0C1B67":-81,"F45EAB0BF97E":-63,"F45EAB0C1978":-87}},{"mac":"I2RXDQTQT60E","name":"B41","desc":"B41","loc":{"lat":41.819086,"lng":1.980764,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-81,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-91,"F45EAB142A61":-89,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-86,"F45EAB08AAAD":-87,"F45EAB0C1B67":-85,"F45EAB0BF97E":-66,"F45EAB0C1978":-89}},{"mac":"I94JR5K0BKTH","name":"B44","desc":"B44","loc":{"lat":41.819125,"lng":1.980727,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":860528,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-91,"F45EAB142A61":-82,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-90,"F45EAB08AAAD":-84,"F45EAB0C1B67":-87,"F45EAB0BF97E":-85,"F45EAB0C1978":-87}}]
```

This JSON is stored in Cassandra Database in column "data" (the id is a uuid and the data column JSON `json.dumps(result))` ):

```
INSERT INTO monitor (id, data) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Well, I make a SELECT to get all rows stored in Database. The Select is:

```
SELECT data from monitor
```

And get:

```
<cassandra.cluster.ResultSet object at 0x7f1610771fd0>
```

**I will create a Pandas Dataframe with this JSON but I don't know how I can do this...**
I try to make a list with the rows (`rs = list(rows)`) and print `rs` This is the result:

```
Row(data='[{"rss": ...
```

**FYI:** The Dataframe I will create should have the following structure:

mac | name | desc | lat | lng | lrrt

Thanks!!!

Comment: post the exact input data. If it's a json fragment posted above - it's not valid. If it's `rows` - post a testable set of rows

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry, I update the Question with the full JSON. This JSON is one row in Database,